# ASP.NET WebForm dropdownList event not firing

Tags: javascript, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I trying to call OnSelectedIndexChanged event in ASP.NET 3.5 WebForm but event is not firing for some reason. I have tested this piece of code on another application and is working....

```
 <cc1:SpiffyPanel ID="pnlGrade" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="field">
                    Grade
                </td>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="answer"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGrade" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGrade_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>              
  </cc1:SpiffyPanel>
```

...

```
 protected void ddlGrade_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            DropDownList _dropdownObj = (DropDownList)sender;

            var selectValue = _dropdownObj.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: I can only guess that you rebind the combo upon each postback, however, how you actually bind it and where remains a mystery as you haven't shared this detail with us.

Comment: The cc1 is a usercontrol or external component? You try if yourvevent works if you put the drpdown outside the pnlGrade?

Comment: Check if there are any JavaScript errors reported by your browser.